# on using gcloud services i am facing AUTH_PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: gcloud

I want to enable video-stitcher api after checking and enabling all the required conditions i am unable to enable it. Every time i am trying to enable it shows following error:
"Enable services: videostitcher.googleapis.com,livestream.googleapis.com
dai-livestreams
Bind permission denied for service: videostitcher.googleapis.com Service videostitcher.googleapis.com is not available to this consumer. Help Token: AZ-7fWLLCgYt_ROTlcoA0pYw2zmDENH5huxevCPbUYer6-fEf19Z2qAFqPrc9tZr3ey-fanoWeR1CeRQwG6JRNbld8eIIS6vebYXdbNounupX7nH"